# Where can I find the Amazon Resource Number (ARN) in my device pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, pipeline

Where can I find the Amazon Resource Number (ARN) in my device pool?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the URL in the browser when you are editing the pool or the [Network tab in the browser](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) when you update a pool. They usually contain full ARN.

Alternatively, you can get the ARN with AWS CLI, getting [the project ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-projects.html) and then [listing device pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-device-pools.html) of the project.